MSVC FP library float erfcf(x) unexpectedly slow - 2x slower than double erfc(x). Why?
Can someone please verify that the slowness that I see with the MS library implementation of erfcf(x) is reproducible elsewhere. It might just be a benchmarking quirk. Also any suggestions for command line options to make gcc compiled code run faster.
I have adopted @Njuffa's test harness and function erfcf(x) for my experiments on better approximations of the functions that I am interested in. Because the benchmarks take a while and I like to have a progress bar I added a print a "." every so often. The dot printing stalls at tricky value ranges when the range of possible values is swept linearly. I'm using that to guide optimisations.
It has the advantage of system library support for float erfcf(x) and an accurate double erfc(x) as a reference to test against. In the process of testing I have noticed that the Intel 2024.1 ICX library is both fast and accurate, but there are some oddities with the Microsoft MSVC 17.1 implementation and inexplicable (to me) slowness in the dummy loop test when it is compiled with gcc 13.1. I suspect my lack of familiarity with gcc and/or systematic errors arising from running it in a virtual machine may be to blame. I'd be grateful for timings on a native Linux system for comparison. Compiler options are -O3 inline anything for maximum speed and FP mode precise.
This is the minimum reproducible example.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

//#define RANDOM  (1)

// helper routines

float uint32_as_float(uint32_t a)
{
   float r;
   memcpy(&r, &a, sizeof r);
   return r;
}

uint32_t float_as_uint32(float a)
{
   uint32_t r;
   memcpy(&r, &a, sizeof r);
   return r;
}

bool my_isnan(float x)
{
  //    used here so that -ffast-math can't optimise it away (as it does with system isnan()
  //    other options can be used here
  //    return __isnan((double)x);
  //    return __isnanf(x);
  uint32_t ix = float_as_uint32(x);
  //    return !((~ix) & 0x7f800000);  // Intel's choice is slightly faster
  return (ix & 0x7f800000) == 0x7f800000;
}

float erfcdf(float x)
{
  return (float)erfc((double)x);  // shim for calling double precision erfc
}

float dummy(float x)  
{
  return x;  // to determine loop overheads
}

void timefun(const char* name, float (*test_fun)(float), bool verbose)
{
  uint32_t argi, largi = 0;
  float arg, res, sum;
  time_t start0, start, end;
  printf("\nTiming %s\n", name);
  argi = 0;
  sum = 0.0;
  start0 = start = clock();
  do {
      arg = uint32_as_float(argi);
      res = (*test_fun)(arg);
      if (!my_isnan(res)) sum += res;
#ifdef RANDOM
      argi = (argi * 1664525 + 1013904223); // ranqd1 
#else
      argi++;
#endif
      if (verbose && ((argi & 0xff800000) != largi))
      {
          end = clock();
          largi = argi & 0xff800000;
          printf("Exp %x : %6.3f\n", argi >> 20, (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
          start = clock();
      }
      if ((argi & 0x3ffffff) == 0) printf(".");
  } while (argi);
  end = clock();
  printf("\ntime taken %6.2f  sum = %g\n", (float)(end - start0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, sum);
}

int main(void)
{
  timefun("dummy", dummy, false);
  timefun("erfcf", erfcf, false);
  timefun("erfcdf", erfcdf, false);
  return 0;
}

It should compile as is on any of gcc, Intel or MS compilers. I'd be interested in benchmarks on other compilers too.
These are the figures. Linear tests every possible bit pattern of x (including Nans) in sequence from 0 to 0xffffffff. Random uses ranqd1 to break any branch prediction and still execute every possible value of x.



Compiler
Dummy Linear
Linear erfcf
Linear erfc
Rand Dummy
Rand erfcf
Rand erfc




gcc 13.1
31
31.6
51.1
38.7
192
169


Intel 2024.1
2.0
37.6
45.0
3.9
46.9
54.3


MS   17.1
2.0
96.2
47.6
4.0
275
125



I'm unhappy with the behaviour of GCC with the dummy(x) routine which simply returns x. It is an order of magnitude slower than the others. It also seems far too slow when fed pseudo random data. I presume that my lack of familiarity with that compiler has led to it being a lot slower than it should be. The summation for dummy will overflow so I suspect that I haven't got the compiler options right to handle that situation efficiently.
The command line I'm using to build it on Linux is:
gcc -O3 -march=native -mavx2 -finline-functions -Winline erfc_njaffa6.cpp -lm

I am fairly convinced that the MS slowness is due to naive processing of denorms in polynomials which can be very slow. Break into the debugger when the dots stall and you will see denorm values for x. MS is the only one where float erfcf speed is 2x slower than erfc for doubles. GCC and Intel the float linear versions of code are both marginally faster ~15% (as you might expect). GCC struggles and is slow for the pseudo random test and I don't understand why. Any suggestions how to make it run faster?
There is also a question of accuracy. My benchmark for that shows that all of the double erfc(x) implementations give 0.5 ULP when rounded to float (not surprisingly), but that only the Intel library implementation for float erfcf(x) achieves sub ULP accuracy (0.82 ULP worst case). GCC comes second with 2.8 ULP and MS trails in third with 5.7 ULP.
So that the MS float erfcf implementation is not only twice as slow as their double implementation but also 10x less accurate as well. Even with the shims to convert to and from double MS erfc(x) is 2x faster than erfcf(x). Most odd...

Note well that double should be considered C's most natural floating-point type.  FP operations and functions on type double are not necessarily any slower than the analogous operations on float, and sometimes the double operations are faster.  When double computations are faster, it's usually because they are better supported by the underlying hardware.  Dunno about erfc / erfcf in particular, though.

"it's usually because they are better supported by the underlying hardware" Well, no. I hardly see how this is possible on a x86-64 CPUs since simple precision instruction are always faster or equally fast to double precision one (the throughput for scalar is often the same and the latency is higher for double precision). AFAIK, this is also true on mainstream ARM CPUs too. In the worst possible case, one can convert a float to double, then call the function and convert it back. This is the only possible case where it can be slower on mainstream CPUs IMHO (for any decent implementation).

Note that subnormal numbers can be slow. In some case, this can make an implementation much slower than another on a given range of input (also possible slower on the full range of float in average due to more subnormal operations even when there is no subnormal inputs). Can you disable subnormals and then check again the performance of the function (with both float/double numbers)?

Measure it separately with subnormals, values in its most-used interval, extreme values, infinities, and NaNs.

@EricPostpischil / @JeromeRichard thanks for the very helpful suggestion. I think that will separate the sheep from the goats. I'll post the results once I have them. The extent 2x of the slowdown here was a big surprise to me. I have noticed before that Intel & gcc float code is marginally faster 10-20% than double but on MS C it is the same or sometimes slower. Many float system library functions use double arithmetic internally.

Re "Intel library implementation for float erfcf(x) achieves sub ULP accuracy (0.82 ULP worst case). GCC comes second with 2.8 ULP and MS trails in third with 5.7 ULP" : Brian Gladman, Vincenzo Innocente, John Mather, Paul Zimmermann, "Accuracy of Mathematical Functions in Single, Double, Double Extended, and Quadruple Precision." 2024. hal-03141101v7 report the following for erfcf: 0.934 ulp for Intel math library, 3.13 ulp for glibc, and 6.66 ulp for MSVC math library.

@njuffa you are right. I was running the function accuracy test in quick mode stepping +32 at a time. When I ran it exhaustively at +1 step I get 0.9332 ulp for Intel math library and 6.6551 ulp for MS which pretty much agrees with your source. Didn't check gcc.

Thanks to the suggestions made above I upgraded my benchmark so that verbose mode now shows the execution time for each possible value of the FP exponent. The results are interesting and highlight problems with both MS & Intel erfcf library implementations.
The time signature for the really very slow (and inaccurate) MS erfcf(x) implementation is below:

Each operation on a denorm adds a hit of 0.3s to the execution time and the worst case it gets to 1.6s for the range -63 to -74 tailing off on either side. You can also see the effects of underflow arising in the region of positive x>10 (orange line).
Zooming into where denorms occur and propagate through the polynomial we see how bad it gets.

This is clearly rather pointless since erfcf(x) == 1 for any value of |x|< 3.0e-8. It also handles raw denorms inputs very slowly as well.
The Intel time signature is better but it too has a problem for x>0. There is still an underflow generated when x>10.2 which makes all those exponents +4 to +128 take 0.2s.

Armed with these data and my new improved ARM remez algorithm code I set about making a gofaster precision float erfcf(x) function and this is the result. You can test it in @njuffa's test harness linked to in the question. It is just sub 1 ULP at 0.946 ULP relative error.
float new_erfcdf(float x)  // computation entirely in double precision to rule out rounding glitches
{
  double s, r, c;
  c = fabs(x); 
  if (c < 4e-8) return 1.0f;
  s = c * c;
  if (c > 10.2) { if (x > 0.0f) return 0.0f; else return 2.0f; } // on MSC this is *much* faster 
  if (c < 0.08) return (float)(1.0 + x * (-1.1283776919236866465056 + s * (0.3752183453419132113961)));
  if (my_isnan(x)) return x + x;
  if (c < 2.1)
  {
    return (float)   (1.0+x*(-1.12837903762067845122478 + s * (0.376124824775496900 + s * (-0.11283152344661124283 + s * (0.02685306318990355076153 + s * (-0.005208108400366166889408 + s * (0.00084248506000537495895 + s * (-0.000114081296888176590432631682 + s * (1.25819680304023068029935e-05 + s * (-1.053171458705915517055e-06 + s * (5.83737961310388214431176e-08 + s * (-1.57325913775639606424677e-09))))))))))) );
  }
  // else 4,4 rational after Njuffa    
  r = (1.031356822232436016816 + c * (0.943286562098123339 + c * (0.453315560300251674 + c * (-3.27806565406628617583e-06)))) / (1.0 + c * (2.19836964842143340 + c * (1.675510512431580478 + c * (0.8032578099371390774))));
  r = r * exp(-s);
  if (x < 0) r = 2.0 - r;
  return (float)r;
}

I tried to make a pure float version but the tricky cancelation of the first three terms in x when x ~ 2 seems to make that impossible so double precision arithmetic has been used to tame it. The code takes 7.9s to complete the sequential benchmark and 26s for random order. This is substantially faster than all the system libraries I have tested. Here is its timing signature (note the change of vertical scale):

It is possible that it could be made a bit faster or more accurate but this is essentially a proof of concept implementation to share. The choice of breakpoints is determined by needing to keep the error budget under control - they could be tweaked to make small improvements to accuracy. This test was done by hand. It is a very worthwhile improvement in speed.
A pure float version would potentially be slightly quicker but it is hopelessly inaccurate for 3 < s < 4. Any thoughts how to fix that? Someone with a better annealing code might be able to bring the coefficients under control but I suspect that there is too much catastrophic cancellation going on in that region to be safe in floats. I will raise this issue of a pure float implementation in a another thread later.

The speed of handling subnormal floating-point operands is very much hardware dependent, so it would be advantageous to note the CPU used to generate the performance data in the answer. It is certainly possible to build hardware that can handle subnormal operands with minimal overhead instead of punting it to a slow microcoded exception handler. No idea where the recent architecture generations from AMD and Intel fall on that spectrum.

@Martin Brown, Aside: Axes in graphs deserves units.

Consider float cf = fabsf(x);  if (cf < 4e-8f) return 1.0f; double c = cf; s = c * c;.  No use to jump to double math right away, yet staying with float may improve time a bit.  Like-wise with some of the if (c > some_double) { test - stay with float until double needed.

Minor: return (float)   (1.0+x*(-1.12837903762067845122478 + s * (0.376124824775496900 + s * (-0.11283152344661124283 + s * (0.02685306318990355076153 + s * (-0.005208108400366166889408 + s * (0.00084248506000537495895 + s * (-0.000114081296888176590432631682 + s * (1.25819680304023068029935e-05 + s * (-1.053171458705915517055e-06 + s * (5.83737961310388214431176e-08 + s * (-1.57325913775639606424677e-09))))))))))) ); --> consider auto-formatting and use a not so large line width.

@chux empirically I determined on the CPU & compilers that I was using Intel and MS there was no discernible timing difference between float and double binary operations. Apart from when the float operations end up with denormals (which happens much sooner there). The advantage of going into doubles immediately means that it avoids any denormal slowdown on x^2. ITYM axes deserve labels (and I have to agree there). Horizontal is FP exponent and vertical is execution time in s. I've noticed that some system math library implementations take the same approach (promote to double internally).
